# DynamoDB: How to call dynamodb api from ZF2 rest application

Tags: mysql, rest, zend-framework2, amazon-dynamodb

I have an existing app with mysql as backend, We are shifting from mysql to DynamoDB, I want to call Dynamodb api from my ZF2 rest.

I am working with this module: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2 (which help to interact with Dynamodb)

Any light on the path would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to accomplished this task by extending *AbstractRestfulController* and we can use Get, Create, Delete methods to call the api

The AWS Module will help in communicating with DynamoDB.